# Organic hydrocarbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

Why new double bond or triple bond creates to the center always? When pentan-2-ol reacts with $\ce{Al2O3}$ ∆ the double bond creates to the 2nd carbon. Can't it create on the 1st carbon?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaitsev's_rule

Answer (score 1):

It can and will form a double bond to the 1st carbon, however it will much more likely form one to the second carbon.

You will get a mixture of both 1-pentene and both *cis*- and *trans*-2-pentene.  The major component will be the *trans*-2-pentene because that is the most stable compound.  Remember, more substituents on a double bond mean the bond is more stabilized for a couple reasons.  Steric interferences mean that *trans-* is more stable as well.

Since the product is more stable, the transition state to form that product is more stable and therefore easiest to form, generally.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate pentan-2-ol to both pent-1-ene and pent-2-ene (and to both stereoisomers of the latter).

To a certain degree, the reagents you use determine which product you get. If you turn the alcohol into a leaving group and then add a strong, sterically demanding base, the pent-1-ene content will increase. If you add a small, mild base, you will observe more pent-2-ene. Careful tuning of reaction conditions often allows for these differences in reactivity.